# Preventing an error message?

Tags: python, sqlite

i am making a check to see wether a field in SQLite has a customer booking id - if it does it will return the row, etc etc. But if they dont i get the following error

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Which i know what it means,nothing is there etc.
But im wondering if theres a way to prevent the error and instead put a message there?

Answer (score 1):

You can always catch the error if you know how to handle it:

```
try:
   do_something_that_raises_error()
except TypeError:
   print("database doesn't have correct info")
   sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for speedy reply - I Tried using this but it still gave the error ? Any advances? :)

Comment: I don't see how that is possible unless you put the try/except around the wrong piece of code.

Comment: @CharlieSay: That's not useful information unless you show us the code that tried it and the error and traceback that you got. If you wrote exactly this code, you certainly would not get a `TypeError` at that point. You might get a _different_ error here, or you might get a `TypeError` from some other code outside the `try`, but without seeing your code, we can't tell you why.

Comment: @abarnert             print '|Do you want to see what seats", row[1] "has booked?|'
            choice = raw_input("|Y/N: ")
            if choice == 'Y':
                try:
                    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM seats WHERE CustID = (?)", (CustID,))
                    rowseat = cur.fetchone()
                    print "|Seats booked:" , rowseat[0]
                    print "|------------------------------------------|"
                except TypeError:
                    print("database doesn't have correct info")
                    sys.exit(1)

Comment: @CharlieSay: And what does the traceback for the `TypeError` say? It could easily be from, e.g., the first `print` line that tries to print `row[1]`. (Also, reading code posted in comments is nearly impossible. Try posting it somewhere like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) and then posting a link here.)

Comment: @CharlieSay: When I try that code (substituting in a simple `cur` that always returns `None` for everything), I get `Seats booked: database doesn't have correct info" printed out, and no traceback. Are you sure that traceback and that code go together?

Comment: @abarnert heres the code at as a bigger picture to give you an idea http://pastebin.com/g8n2k962

Comment: @CharlieSay: I honestly can't imagine how that code could result in that traceback. But if for whatever reason you can't use `try`/`except`, you can always check explicitly instead. Do an `if rowset is None:` check before the `print`.

Comment: @abarnert sorry what part of the code would i insert that then?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are doing something like this:

```
if row['customer_booking_id'] is not None:
```

while your `row` is `None` itself.  Could you please post your code?

Comment: I see your point but this is not what i wanted :) I wanted it so, if there is no row that is equal to the id it prints a custom error message, not the automated one about getting objects.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've caught the error you can also raise a custom error instead of printing:

```
try:
    do_something_that_raises_error()
except TypeError:
    raise MyCustomError("My Custom Message")
```

here's an example custom error definition:

```
class MyCustomError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        Exception.__init__(self,msg)
        self.message = msg
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.message)
```